# Toggle data attribute of nav with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a nav header with a data attribute

```
<nav class="nav-header" data-drawer-display="show" data-drawer-num="0">
```

that sets the display of the navigation to either show or hide on click of a nav link, with `data-drawer-display=""`. I need to be able to toggle the navigation away by clicking on the body of the page with

```
$("body").on("click", function(){});
```

that should toggle the value from `show` to `hide`. I have tried this:

```
$('body').on('click touchstart',function(e){
    $( ".nav-header" ).attr( "data-drawer-display", function( i, val ) {
      return val === 'show'?'hide':'show';
});
```

but the logic seems to be off.

**SOLUTION**

A modified version of @empiric below:

```
$('body').on('touchstart', function(e){
 //keeps nav from closing when clicking in subnav and links
 if ($(e.target).is('.opener, .nav-sub, a')) {
      console.log(target);
      return false;
  }
 //if subnav is open, close on body click.
 $( ".nav-header" ).attr( "data-drawer-display", function( i, val ) {
      return val === 'show' ? 'hide' : '';
      });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the callback of the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)-function the wrong way.

Your `$(this)` will not refer to the element `$('.nav-header')`. In the function scope it is refering to `$('body')` which does not have an attribute `data-drawer-display`.

```
$( ".nav-header" ).attr( "data-drawer-display", function( i, val ) {
  return val === 'show'?'hide':'show';
});
```

should be working for you.

---

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6erzka7o/2/)**

**Edit**

to avoid closing the `nav` when clicking on it (through event propagation) you can check for the clicked element:

```
if ($(e.target).is('nav')) {
    return false;
}
```

**[Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/6erzka7o/3/)**

Comment: 2nd argument of [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) can be either a String or a function - I don't believe he's using it incorrectly.

Comment: @Tibrogargan but `$(this)` is not refering to the element with the attribute. In his case it is refering to `$('body')` which is wrong. I assumed he want to get the current value of the elements attribute. I could've mentioned that in my answer, yes.

Comment: The problem now, is that when you click one of the nav links, it sets the data-drawer-display to hide. Clicking the body shows the nav on click, but releasing the mouse hides the nav again.

Comment: @user3438917 I assume that's because `nav` is a child of `body` so the event is always firing. I'll update my answer

Comment: Hmm, this is still causing the nav to toggle on and off, when clicking on the links:

`$('body').on('click touchstart',function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is('nav')) {
          return false;
        }
        $( ".nav-header" ).attr( "data-drawer-display", function( i, val ) {
          return val === 'show' ? 'hide' : 'show';
        });
});`

Comment: Just saw you had `nav[data-drawer-display="hide"] {
    display: none;
  }' in the fiddle, but using that in my css hides the nav on page load. Also, the issue with your fiddle is that the nav reopens with body click. Clicking on the body should only *close* the nav.

Comment: @user3438917 was just an example. Should not represent your actual site setup. To your second point: Thats how `return val === 'show'?'hide':'show';` works. If it should only be closed, replace the second `show` to `''`.

Comment: @empiric - I had to slightly modify your answer, but selecting it as the correct one. Thanks!